# Cannot read property success of undefined using Reactjs Toastr

Tags: reactjs, redux

Am working with **react toastr**  from this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastr for my react-redux form. 
i have installed as `npm install --save react-toastr` and I have made import as per requirements

```
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastr";
import { ToastMessage } from "react-toastr";
import { ToastMessageAnimated } from "react-toastr";
let container;
```

at **src/index.html** i have **toastr.min.css and toastr.animate.css** files

At RegisterPage Component when I click at Test Toastr Button as per code below, everything works fine

```
 <div className="container">
  <ToastContainer
    ref={ref => container = ref}
    className="toast-top-right"
  />
  <h1>
    React-Toastr
    <small>React.js toastr component</small>
  </h1>
  <div className="btn-container">
    <button
      className="primary"
      onClick={() =>
        container.success(`hi! Now is `, `success`, {
          closeButton: true,})
      }
    >
     Test Toastr
    </button>

  </div>

</div>
```

Here is what am trying to do.
I want to display toastr message alert once form registeration is successful but it shows error

**bundle.js:36689 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined** when I added this code below at **user.service.js** files

```
setTimeout(()=>{ this.container.success(`hi! jmarkatti `, `success`, {closeButton: true,}); }, 400);
```

Here is the **user.service.js** files

```
import config from 'config';
import { authHeader } from '../_helpers';

import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastr";
import { ToastMessage } from "react-toastr";
import { ToastMessageAnimated } from "react-toastr";
let container;

export const userService = {

    register,
    update,
};


function register(user) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',

return fetch(`../register.php`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse)
        .then(res => {

            if (res) {

//setTimeout(()=>{ this.container.success('Data added successfully'); }, 400);
setTimeout(()=>{ this.container.success(`hi! jmarkatti `, `success`, {closeButton: true,}); }, 400);
console.log('Data added suucessfully');
            }

            return user;
        });


}
```

The code below is the  **RegisterPage** Component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { userActions } from '../_actions';

import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastr";
import { ToastMessage } from "react-toastr";
import { ToastMessageAnimated } from "react-toastr";
let container;

class RegisterPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                username: '',
                password: ''
            },
            submitted: false
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        const { user } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            user: {
                ...user,
                [name]: value
            }
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        const { user } = this.state;
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        if (user.firstName && user.lastName && user.username && user.password) {
            dispatch(userActions.register(user));
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { registering  } = this.props;
        const { user, submitted } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <h2>Test Toastr</h2>

 <div className="container">
  <ToastContainer
    ref={ref => container = ref}
    className="toast-top-right"
  />
  <h1>
    React-Toastr
    <small>React.js toastr component</small>
  </h1>
  <div className="btn-container">
    <button
      className="primary"
      onClick={() =>
        container.success(`hi! Jmarkatti `, `success`, {
          closeButton: true,})
      }
    >
     Test Toastr
    </button>

  </div>

</div>

                <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

// form input removed to reduce code

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                        {registering && 
                                         }

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { registering } = state.registration;
    return {
        registering
    };
}

const connectedRegisterPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(RegisterPage);
export { connectedRegisterPage as RegisterPage };
```

**An Updates is Here**

**user.action.js** code

```
function register(user) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request(user));

        userService.register(user)
            .then(
                user => { 

/*
                   dispatch(success());
                    history.push('/login');
                    dispatch(alertActions.success('Registration successful'));
*/

                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error(error.toString()));
                }
            );
    };
```

**user.reducer.js** codes

```
import { userConstants } from '../_constants';

export function registration(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case userConstants.REGISTER_REQUEST:
      return { registering: true };
    case userConstants.REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      return {};
    case userConstants.REGISTER_FAILURE:
      return {};
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you expect `this.container` in service to contain the same ref as `let container` do in your component's code? are you passing ref somehow from component to service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

Change

```
   setTimeout(()=>{ this.container.success(`hi! jmarkatti `, `success`, {closeButton: true,}); }, 400);
```

To

```
    setTimeout(()=>{ 
            if(this.container){
                     this.container.success(`hi! jmarkatti `, `success`, {closeButton: true,}); 
             }
     }, 400);
```

Comment: Sir Think-Twice. I have implemented your solutions and the error is gone but the toastr alert is still not showing after form submission. does it mean that its not accessing   all the toastr css files(toastr.min.css and toastr.animate.css files)  at src/index.html. The toastr response/output templates is still at RegisterPage component.  I have also added the user.action.js and user.reducer.js. Please can you help me further Sir. between thank you so far. waiting for your response